# Filling Data with VBA Code by User Form in Certain Row

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a case in this VBA Code.

Basically, I have 2 sheets:

- Lending & Funding
- MUFG Client

What I want to do is adding a data in Lending & Funding sheet starts from A7507 horizontally and in MUFG Client starts from A103 as well.

This is the VBA code that I have so far

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
whichSheet = InputBox("In which sheet do you wish to enter data? Specify Sheet as Lending & Funding or MUFG Client only.", "Sheet Name")
If whichSheet = "" Then
MsgBox "You didn't specify a sheet!"
Exit Sub
End If

Worksheets(whichSheet).Activate
Dim lastrow
lastrow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 
lastrow = lastrow + 1
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A7507:A" & lastrow), Cells(lastrow, 1)) > 1 Then
MsgBox "Duplicate Data! Only Unique CIFs allowed", vbCritical, "Remove Data", Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A7507:A" & lastrow), Cells(lastrow, 1)) = 1 Then
answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
If answer = vbYes Then
Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Text
Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
Cells(lastrow, 6) = TextBox6.Text
Cells(lastrow, 7) = TextBox7.Text
Cells(lastrow, 8) = TextBox8.Text
Cells(lastrow, 9) = TextBox9.Text
Cells(lastrow, 10) = TextBox10.Text
Cells(lastrow, 11) = TextBox11.Text
Cells(lastrow, 12) = TextBox12.Text
Cells(lastrow, 13) = TextBox13.Text
Cells(lastrow, 14) = TextBox14.Text
Cells(lastrow, 15) = TextBox15.Text
End If
End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub
```

The thing is whenever I add data in MUFG Client, it will fill row 3 not 103.

This is what happened when you add data(s) in Lending & Funding

[image]
[image]

It Works!

But when I add data(s) in MUFG Client

[image]

Instead of row 103, The data(s) was added in row 3. It Doesn't Work!

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: You don't have headers in your data tables?  It's difficult otherwise to see how that `End(xlUp)` gets to row 6...

Comment: @TimWilliams my header in Lending & Funding starts on cell A2 and header in MUFG Client starts from cell A5. So, What should I change in my current VBA code in order to make it can be filled on A103 in MUFG Client sheet?

Comment: `If lastrow<103 Then lastrow=103`

Comment: @TimWilliams It still doesn't work like what I wanted. I guess it needs some kind of separation code to differentiate between Lending & Funding sheet and MUFG Client Sheet.

Comment: Yes you definitely need that also.

Comment: @TimWilliams do you know the code or what should I type to add in my current VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is a little confusing, as we can't see your sheets. But here is an attempt at rewriting your code to :

1. Not use `Activate`.
2. Remove need to enter Sheet name.
3. Force the `lastrow` value to a minimum based on the sheet selected.
4. Not add part of the record if user doesn't want record added.
5. Write to debug window what was written to assist debugging.

---

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim whichsheet As String
    whichsheet = InputBox("In which sheet do you wish to enter data? Enter 1 for Lending & Funding or 2 for MUFG Client", "Sheet selector")
    
    If whichsheet <> "1" And whichsheet <> "2" Then
       MsgBox "You didn't specify a valid sheet!"
       Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim firstusablerow As Long
    If whichsheet = "1" Then
       firstusablerow = 7507
       whichsheet = "Lending & Funding"
    Else
       firstusablerow = 103
       whichsheet = "MUFG Client"
    End If
    
    With Worksheets(whichsheet)
        Dim lastrow As Long
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        
        If lastrow < firstusablerow Then lastrow = firstusablerow
        
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range("A" & firstusablerow & ":A" & lastrow), .Cells(lastrow, 1)) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "Duplicate Data! Only Unique CIFs allowed", vbCritical, "Remove Data", .Cells(lastrow, 1) = ""
        Else
            answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add the record?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Add Record")
            If answer = vbYes Then
                Debug.Print "Writing " & TextBox1.Text & " to row " & lastrow & " on sheet " & whichsheet
                .Cells(lastrow, 1) = TextBox1.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 2) = TextBox2.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 3) = TextBox3.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 4) = TextBox4.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 5) = TextBox5.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 6) = TextBox6.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 7) = TextBox7.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 8) = TextBox8.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 9) = TextBox9.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 10) = TextBox10.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 11) = TextBox11.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 12) = TextBox12.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 13) = TextBox13.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 14) = TextBox14.Text
                .Cells(lastrow, 15) = TextBox15.Text
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already added this code to my VBA but it doesn't work. It says "You didn't specify a valid sheet!" although I wrote Lending & Funding or MUFG Client. The thing is with my previous VBA code above, I only want to add data starts from row 7507 in Lending & Funding sheet and row 103 in MUFG Client sheet.

Comment: it should work, make sure you enter `lending & funding` or `mufg client` - the code is written to ignore case.

Comment: Might be easier just to ask the user to enter either "l" or "m" - easier for them and there's less chance they won't enter it exactly right...

Comment: @CLR well it did work for Lending & Funding sheet. But it didn't work for MUFG client sheet. when the question pops up "Are you sure you want to add the record?" and I clicked Yes, It didn't fill the data. Hmm I think something's wrong.

Comment: @CLR ups, sorry, it turns out did work on mufg client too, but it fills the data in row 7507 same as lending & funding sheet. lol. I think we need to change the previous code just a little.

Comment: Okay, I'm going to post some altered code that you should be able to tweak so you start on the right row for the right sheet. It makes it easier to select the sheet, although if I were building this myself, I'd probably make the user select the sheet name on the UserForm itself rather than as a MsgBox.

Comment: @CLR IT REALLY WORKS. Thank you so much for your help once again. I already voted the answer and accepted it :D

Comment: @CLR if you have a spare time, I also posted another question that needs to be solved [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62786618/hide-rows-vba-code-mismatch-with-same-duplication] . Thank you so much in advance :)